How to pass argument into schedule_task for Locust?
Let's say that my test case is to get list of articles at news site and make a comment for the articles.
Here is how my code may look:
class MyTasks(TaskSet):
  def post_comment(self. article_id: int):
    self.client.post(
      f"/{article_id}/comment",
      json={"body": "some random comment"},
      name=f"comment_for_{article_id}",
    )

  @task
  def get_articles(self):
    with self.client.get(
      "/articles",
      name="get_articles",
    ) as response:
      if response.status_code == 200:
        for article_id in response.json()["article_ids"]:
          # I want to add scheduled task for specific article
          # to write comment for the article
          # BUT! I can not pass article ID?!
          self.schedule_task(
            self.post_comment,
            first=True,
            # how to add arguments for post_comment here?
          )

As you can see it is not possible to pass arguments to any task in Locust.
Does Locust really lacks so obvious and necessary feature like passing arguments to task?
Here is schedule_task's code:
def schedule_task(self, task_callable, first=False):
    """
    Add a task to the User's task execution queue.

    :param task_callable: User task to schedule.
    :param first: Optional keyword argument. If True, the task will be put first in the queue.
    """
    if first:
        self._task_queue.appendleft(task_callable)
    else:
        self._task_queue.append(task_callable)

And I couldn't find how to pass parameters.
So the question is how it supposed to pass arguments and custom parameters for a specific task in Locust?

Do you have to manipulate tasks? I'd just call self.post_comment(article_id) directly.
Oh, and there's no point in using a with-block, unless you are manipulating the status of the response (in which case you'd also have to pass catch_response=True).
class MyTasks(TaskSet):
  def post_comment(self. article_id: int):
    self.client.post(
      f"/{article_id}/comment",
      json={"body": "some random comment"},
      name=f"comment_for_{article_id}",
    )

  @task
  def get_articles(self):
    response = self.client.get(
      "/articles",
      name="get_articles",
    )
    if response.status_code == 200:
      for article_id in response.json()["article_ids"]:
        self.post_comment(article_id)



Separate actions to tasks make code easier to read (one task == one action), 2. I'm not too familiar with Locust but I suppose that tasks has some helpful benefits like concurrency control, scheduling, etc, 3. It is possible to set wait_time to wait between tasks, and I want to use the feature in real life, 4. And finally, if do not use tasks, why it needed at all?.


tasks are mainly used for wait_time and weight (task selection). If you want to do sleeps between parts of a task you can just call time.sleep(x), it is essentially the same as that which is done between tasks. Concurrency is managed on the User level, nothing for tasks to worry about.

Currently I decided to use Python object features to store extra arguments for task. Not sure how much this way is effective, but at least it works:
# Here is Commenter class with specific article_id stored
# as an instance attribute
class Commenter:

  def __init__(self, article_id: int) -> None:
    self.article_id = article_id

  # when instance will be called as task
  # this function with pre-saved article_id will be executed
  def __call__(self, task: "MyTasks") -> None:
    task.client.post(
      f"/{self.article_id}/comment",
      json={"body": "some random comment"},
      name=f"comment_for_{self.article_id}",
    )


class MyTasks(TaskSet):

  @task
  def get_articles(self):
    with self.client.get(
      "/articles",
      name="get_articles",
    ) as response:
      if response.status_code == 200:
        for article_id in response.json()["article_ids"]:
          self.schedule_task(
            # instantiate Commenter object and set article_id
            # to be able call it in future
            Commenter(article_id),
            first=True,
          )

